# Naming in segwit script

Tags: transactions, address, segregated-witness

I have some doubts about naming in witness script/transaction.

**P2SH-P2WSH (multisig)**

`WITNESS_SCRIPT = OP_3 <public key1> <public key2> <public key3> <OP_2>`

(is it witness script or redeem script? For now I will call Witness script)

`SCRIPTHASH= SHA256 (WITNESS_SCRIPT)`

is it Witness script Hash or redeem script Hash?

`REDEEM_SCRIPT=0020+SCRIPTHASH`

is it redeem script? Maybe it's the redeem script because it is in Scriptsig. (Witness version + Witness program)

In scriptPubKey 
hash160 of `(0020+SCRIPTHASH)`.

What is its name? Hash160 of ?

And We have `OP_HASH160 <Redeem script hash?> OP_EQUAL`

**P2SH-P2WPKH**

`KEYHASH = hash160(<public key>)`

`REDEEM_SCRIPT=0014+KEYHASH`

is it redeem script or witness script? For now I Will call redeem script.

In scriptPubKey
hash160 of `(0020+SCRIPTHASH)`.

What is its name? Hash160 of ?

And We have `OP_HASH160 <Redeem script hash?> OP_EQUAL`

**P2WPKH NATIVE**

WITNESS SCRIPT = `hash160(<public key>)`

In scriptpubkey
`0014+WITNESS_SCRIPT`

`OP_0 <20 bytes witness script hash>`

**P2WSH NATIVE**

WITNESS SCRIPT = `<OP_2> <pubkey1><pubkey2><pubkey3><OP_3> <OP_CHECKMULTISIG>`

WITNESS_SCRIPT_HASH = `HASH160 (WITNESS SCRIPT)`

In scriptpubkey

`0020+WITNESS_SCRIPT_HASH`

`OP_0 <32 bytes witness script hash>`

P2WPKH NATIVE and P2WSH NATIVE should be ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**P2SH-P2WSH:**

- Witness script: `OP_3 <public key1> <public key2> <public key3> OP_2 OP_CHECKMULTSIG`
- Witness program: `SHA256(witness script)`
- redeemScript: `OP_0 <witness program>`
- Script hash: `Hash160(redeemScript)`
- scriptPubKey: `OP_HASH160 <script hash> OP_EQUAL`

**P2SH-P2WPKH** (I believe that's what you meant instead of "P2WSH-P2PKH"):

- Witness program: `Hash160(public key)`
- redeemScript: `OP_0 <witness program>`
- Script hash: `Hash160(redeemScript)`
- scriptPubKey: `OP_HASH160 <script hash> OP_EQUAL`

**P2WSH-P2PKH** (native P2WSH, but with a P2PKH script inside):

- Witness script: `OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <Hash160(pubkey)> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG`
- Witness program: `SHA256(witness script)`
- scriptPubKey: `OP_0 <witness program>`

Note that you should use P2WPKH instead of this.

**Native P2WPKH**

- Witness program: `Hash160(public key)`
- scriptPubKey: `OP_0 <witness program>`

**Native P2WSH**

- Witness script: `OP_3 <public key1> <public key2> <public key3> OP_2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG`
- Witness program: `SHA256(witness script)`
- scriptPubKey: `OP_0 <witness program>`

Comment: Thanks again for your time, it's an amazing answer for me. I don't understand this script `P2WSH-P2PKH` the third one. I create a bash script to create P2WSH-P2PKH native (bc) where the Witness script is `OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <Hash160(pubkey)> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG`. But I have the last scenario (`Native P2WSH`), than I don't have redeem script and script hash.thanks for your advice (Note that you should use P2WPKH instead of this.) but my purpose now is to study, I don't use it :).

Comment: I have another question (sorry). You said "P2SH-P2WSH" `redeemScript: OP_0 <witness program>`. When I use `signrawtransactionwithkey` I need to put `redeemScript` in `witnessScript` value. Then why use the name `redeemScript` when I need to use in `witnessScript` value during `signrawtransactionwithkey`?

Comment: Update last question. If I change WitnessScript with redeemScript in `signrawtransactionwithkey` works as well. ( I mean the Object key )

Comment: @monkeyUser signrawtransaction* secretly doesn't really care about what you name things; it just needs to know all the scripts involved in order to sign.

Comment: I don't understand your first question (about P2WSH-P2PKH).

Comment: When I create P2WSH-P2SH (Native and with P2PKH script) I have the same items of Native P2WSH (multisig).

Comment: What do you mean by "items"? There would not be any redeemScript in the native witness cases, only in P2SH-wrapped cases.

Comment: you said "P2WSH-P2PKH (native P2WSH, but with a P2PKH script inside)". It's native, for that reason I don't understand Why I should have `redeemScript` `Script hash`. Thanks

Comment: Oh, my mistake! Fixed.

Comment: thanks for your time, really.